# Ajax send data to Node.js client then send to Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible that jquery.Ajax will send data to Node.js client,then after it receive the data will be send to Node.js server ?. Is this possible ?

> myajax

```
$.ajax({
   type:'post'
   data:{data:hello},
   url: '' //here I don't know how to point to node.js client
   success:function(data){


   } 

});
```

> servarapp.js

```
 var net = require('net');

var clients = [];

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

   clients.push(socket);


});

  server.listen(1337,'localhost',function(){
   console.log("server is listening in port 1337");
});
```

> client.js

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server!);
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); 
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what type of setup would this be? I'm not sure what you're asking. BTW why are you putting a space between the last word and the question mark?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, what I want to achieve is that I want my jqeruy.ajax() can send data to client.js then the Node client.js will send this data to Node server.js ,is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

An AJAX request from a browser can only be sent to an HTTP server. In your `client.js` you seem to have created a Socket on port 1337 but this cannot work because AJAX is only through HTTP protocol. For this to work you can use some HTTP framework such as [`express`](http://expressjs.com/) so that you create an HTTP server.

Comment: I am using net in server

Comment: Now that you have updated your questions with more details you need an HTTP server in order to send the AJAX request to. In your client.js you seem to just have opened a TCP socket but that cannot work. You will need an HTTP middleware.